# Input doesn't listen to the if statment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a input that generates a number upon another input keyup. however it should only generate this number when my checkbox is checked. if it doesn't it shouldn't generate there nothing. but instead it generates me the number if the checkbox is check or not .. even though the function exists only in the checked mode.. i have no idea what went wrong:

the checkbox

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="switch switch-primary">
<input class="multi-transaction" type="checkbox" name="switch" data-plugin-ios-switch="">
</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.multi-transaction').click(function () {
    var sum = $('.amount-czk');
    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
        sum.prop("disabled", false); // check
        sum.css('border-color', '#ccc');
        sum.val(0);

        $('.amount-czk').on('keyup', function () {
            var amount = parseInt($('.give-me-money').val()); // amount to pay in eur example 520
            var amount_wr = parseInt($('.amount-czk').val()); // type how much we got in any currency
            $('.currency-czk').val((amount_wr / amount ? amount_wr / amount : 0).toFixed(2));
        });
        //curchange(true);
    }

    else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
        console.log('do nothing');
    }
});
```

Instead of only giving me the console.log the input keyup function stays working..

Comment: Why are you binding the keyup everytime the checkbox is clicked?

Answer (score 3):

Don't bind event handlers inside another handlers, they will multiply soon causing strange issues. Try something like this instead:

```
$('.multi-transaction').click(function () {
    var sum = $('.amount-czk');
    if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
        sum.prop("disabled", false); // check
        sum.css('border-color', '#ccc');
        sum.val(0);
        //curchange(true);
    } else if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
        console.log('do nothing');
    }
});

$('.amount-czk').on('keyup', function () {
    if ($('.multi-transaction').prop('checked')) {
        var amount = parseInt($('.give-me-money').val()); // amount to pay in eur example 520
        var amount_wr = parseInt($('.amount-czk').val()); // type how much we got in any currency
        $('.currency-czk').val((amount_wr / amount ? amount_wr / amount : 0).toFixed(2));   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try in if condition...

```
if($(this).prop('checked')) {
    // something when checked
} else {
    // something else when not
}
```